# Uploading files to local Geoprocessing service

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service, cors

I am trying to upload csv file to geoprocessing service, everything works fine if I replaced the URL and uploaded the file to any GP service published by ESRI but when I try to upload to my local GP service it fails. I am using ArcGIS Server 10.4.1 but I'm not sure what did I miss to configure in my service.

```
var UploadURL="https://MyServer/arcgis/rest/services/Density/GPServer/uploads/upload";
//var UploadURL="http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/911CallsHotspot/GPServer/uploads/upload";
esriConfig.defaults.io.corsEnabledServers.push(UploadURL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable **uploads** on the geoprocessing service. You can enable this when publishing, or after the fact through the service properties.

Check the [Capabilities](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/geoprocessing-service-settings-capabilities.htm) tab for the check box to enable it.